# Why $M \otimes M$ does not have a ring structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, exterior-algebra

I am reading some section about tensor algebras, and I don't have clear the idea on why $M \otimes M$ dont have a ring structure, where $M$ is an $R$-module. R is commutative and $1 \in R$. So far my knowledge goes, i think it is because the product $m_1 \otimes m_2 \notin M$. can someone explain better to me why it is?

In general I don't understand quite well the idea of tensor products at all.

Thanks

Comment: Are you only assuming that $M$ is some $R$-module?  Or is $M$ a ring itself?

Comment: $M$ is an $R$-Module

Comment: I am not sure I understand... A ring has multiplication, for such a question to make sense, there should be a _natural_ multiplication in the mathematical objects, that though fails to satisfy some properties and hence the object is not a ring. Then it makes sense to ask "why is this multiplication not good enough"... In this case I don't see what could be a multiplication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An $R$-algebra structure on $M\otimes M$ would looks like a map $(M\otimes M) \otimes (M \otimes M) \to M\otimes M$.   The natural structure map you are equipped with is merely a bilinear map $M \times M \to M\otimes M$, which does not have the right domain to tell you how to define how to multiply two basic tensors $m_1 \otimes m_2$ and $m_3\otimes m_4$.

Note that there is a reasonable map of this form if you already have a multiplication $M\otimes M \to M$, in which case you can define $(m_1 \otimes m_2)\cdot (m_3 \otimes m_4) = (m_1m_3, m_2m_4)$.

Comment: Basically, since there is not an action to perform the multiplication of tensors, it does not have the ring structure, right? I was reading my book and it says that the tensor algebra  of $M$ fix this problem, not understand how?

Comment: It fixes it analogously to how the free group generated by a set formally adds in a multiplication.  The tensor algebra contains a copy of $M^{\otimes n}$ for every $n$, which allows you to take arbitrary elements $a_1 \otimes \dots \otimes a_i$ and $b_1 \otimes \dots \otimes b_j$ and define their product as $a_1 \otimes \dots \otimes a_i \otimes b_1 \otimes \dots \otimes b_j$.